# Mutex not initialized

Tags: linux

Does anyone know if when creating a mutex, it's a must to initialize it or can i lock it directly without calling pthread_mutex_init?

I have done a sample application that simulates a deadlock just to make sure the mutex work and have declared 2 mutexes(to create the deadlock) in the following way:

```
static pthread_mutex_t fastmutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t fastmutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

The deadlock perfectly works which makes sense since it's initialized with some defaults.
On the other hand when doing the exact same thing with this:

```
static pthread_mutex_t fastmutex1;
static pthread_mutex_t fastmutex2;
```

I expected that not to work but the deadlock appeared in the exact same way as the previous example.

By the way I am running that on Linux kernel 2.6.18

Thx for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Debian/Sid/AMD64 system, `/usr/include/pthread.h` contains

```
 # define PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER \
   { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, { 0, 0 } } }
```

This means that (on my system) a `pthread_mutex_t` is valuably initialized to all zeros. And a static variable is initialized (in C) to all zeros, which happens to be the same at runtime (and explains the behavior you've got).

However, there is no guarantee that `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` will stay the same, or that is is all zeros on other systems. So you better explicitly initialize a static  `pthread_mutex_t`  variable with it.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [documentation](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (And everything else I've ever read or personally done with pthreads):

> Mutex variables must be declared with type pthread_mutex_t, and must be initialized before they can be used.

I suspect anything else is going to trigger undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is usually used for **statically allocated mutexes** ( so syntax 1 is the right way to go).
In various implementation defined ([AIX](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/pthread_mutex_destroy_init.htm), [LINUX](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init), [SOLARIS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-6867/sync-113/index.html)),  seems to converge on your case.

In all other cases you should by default try to initialize the mutex as in

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,0);
```

which will try to initialize it to `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` .

Keep in mind that error checking can be done ( and is actually done as such in STL) later when trying to acquire the mutex;

```
static int e = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
if( e ) { 
  throw std::string("Everything is crazy in here");
}
```

since the return value will equal `EINVAL` in case the mutex has not been initialized.